# Asus X550C Launch CSM blurred out

Tags: 64-bit, asus, bios

I have an Asus X550c. I have been looking online on how to install Ubuntu on it. It says that in the BIOS I need to enable,  Launch CSM. I tried to enable it but it is blurred out and I can't change it from Disabled to Enabled.

How do I un-blur it so I can change it?

Comment: First of all you must disable secure boot and then your CSM when enable

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

The souloution is reset and then go into the bios via F2 and it will then allow you to enable Launch CSM